# Ansible callback plugin exception

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to run a playbook from within another playbook with the command:

```
- name: "{{lookup('pipe','date +{{date_format}}')}} - It runs the command Ansible-Playbook installDotnet.yml in .Net-SRV"
      command: ansible-playbook installDotnet.yml
    - debug: var=installDotnet.stdout_lines
```

the installDotnet.yml does not seem to start at all and the command above gets stuck on

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'

After a long time I get the error 

[WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_failed) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.default.CallbackModule object at 0x7f98a75e2d10>):
Callback Exception: 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 374, in send_callback
    method(*new_args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py", line 63, in v2_runner_on_failed
    self._display.display("fatal: [%s]: FAILED! => %s" % (result._host.get_name(), self._dump_results(result._result)), color=C.COLOR_ERROR)
                to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbooks/Scripts_yml/install_optima.retry
```

I'm using a callback_plugin (profile_tasks) for printing out more infos on dates.
I'd like to specify that this was working before and no one changed these playbooks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What your task do? Are you using custom callback plugin? Custom module? Can you give us more info about your problem?

Comment: I've updated the main post with more information. Thanks

Comment: As it seems, your problem is only because you dont have `register: installDotnet` on your `command` task and i dont know if it was when you pasted your yaml here but your debug task is not where it should be idented. Also, you dont need to invoke ansible-playbook again. You can simply run your tasks inside your main playbook by `import_playbook` or `include_tasks`